# How to reinitialize jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to reinitialize a jQuery datatable?  I even tried to remove table element.  Still that table is displaying.  My code is like this:

```
function removeExistingDataTableReference(tableid)
{
    if(oTable !=null)
    {
        oTable.fnDestroy();
    }

    if(document.getElementById(tableid)){
      document.getElementById(tableid).innerHTML="";
    }

    oTable=null;

    try
    {
        if(oTable !=null)
        {
            //oTable.fnDestroy();
            alert("error in fndestroy");
        }

        oTable=null;

        if(document.getElementById(tableid)){
            document.getElementById(tableid).innerHTML="";
        }

        if(document.getElementById("FTable"))
        {
            removeElement(document.getElementById("FTable"));   
        }

    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("Error happend:"+e.message);
    }

}

function removeElement(element) 
{   
  try
  {
       var elem = document.getElementById('FTable');
       elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
       //ert(element.parentNode.id);
       //element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
       alert("removed");
       return true;
   }
   catch(e)
   {
      alert(e.message);
   }

   return false;

}
```

How can I do that?  After Search button click table is loaded.  Again, when I search with another search parameter, table should load with new data.  That is not happening.  How to fix it??

Table is initialized like this:

```
function createDataTable()
{
    try
    {
         oTable = $('#FTable').dataTable( {
             "bDestroy":true,
             "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollXInner": tablewidth+"px",
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bSort":false,
            "iDisplayLength" : 50,
            "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 18, 50, -1], [10, 18, 50, "All"]]
        } );

        new FixedColumns( oTable, {
            "iLeftColumns": 1,
            "iRightColumns": 1
        } );
    }
    catch (e)
    {
    alert(e.message);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reinitialize the datatable by clearing it and then adding the element using `fnAddData()`.

First check whether the `dataTable` exists or not. The function `fnClearTable()` will clear the data from table.

In the code, `dataTable` is datatable variable and `results` is the `id` of table.

```
if(typeof dataTable === 'undefined'){
    dataTable = $('#results').dataTable({ 
       "aLengthMenu": [
           [25, 50, 100, 200],
           [25, 50, 100, 200]
        ], 
        "iDisplayLength" : 25,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    }); 
}else dataTable.fnClearTable();
```

Then again add the data using fnAddData.

```
dataTable.fnAddData( [key, assignee, summary, status, days]);
```

Comment: i am not using fnAddData.Each time i creating a html table dynamically then i convert it to datatable(ie by calling createDataTable() function)

Comment: How are you creating the table dynamically? You can't have two instance of datatable on the same table. You can create table dynamically using fnAddData too and this is the correct way AFAIK

Comment: first i will create html table by adding td and tr dynamically....then i will call initialization function

Comment: Yeah. but the table should be in <thead></thead> <tbody></tbody> format. Then how are you deleting and rebuilding the table

Comment: ya everything i will create dynamically..Each search button click is one ajax request..So every time if table is not existing i will first create that table and row will get dynamically added to that table.If already existing i will remove existing table and create new table based on ajax response

Comment: But datatable will not be able to perceive the changes if you do it like this. So you have to use datatable's own API and its pretty simple and straightforward

Comment: but how would datatable know about it?

Comment: so each time after creating dynamic table ,i am calling initialization script..then it should happen right??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27610/discussion-between-android-decoded-and-vmb)

Answer (score 0):

You may use fnReloadAjax

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/256/fnreloadajax/p1

```
oTable = $('#FTable').dataTable( {
     "bDestroy":true,
     "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "sScrollXInner": tablewidth+"px",
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "bSort":false,
    "iDisplayLength" : 50,
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 18, 50, -1], [10, 18, 50, "All"]]
} );

function reinit(){
    oTable.fnReloadAjax( 'media/examples_support/json_source2.txt' );
}
```