# Sort-arrow in datatable appears more than once if destroy is set to true

Tags: javascript, datatable

I need to reinitialize my datatable on every click of a submit button. I set `destroy : true` to achieve this. But every time the datatable re-initializes, the number of sort-arrows that appear for each column increases by one. How can I prevent this from happening? Here is my javascript code. Every time the user clicks on submit, processFormData is called, which calls initializeDataTable after validation of form fields.

```
var firstName = "";
var lastName = "";
var country = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userDetails').dataTable();
});

function processFormData() {

    firstName = document.userDetailsTable.firstName.value;
    lastName = document.userDetailsTable.lastName.value;
    country = document.userDetailsTable.country.value;

    if (document.userDetailsTable.firstName.value == ""
            || document.userDetailsTable.lastName.value == ""
            || document.userDetailsTable.country.value == "") {
        bootbox.alert("Please fill in all fields!");
    } else {

        initializeDataTable();
    }
    return false;
}

function initializeDataTable() {

    $('#userDetailsTable').dataTable({
                "destroy" : true,
        "pageLength" : 12,
        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : '/fetchSearchResults',
            "type" : 'POST',
            "data" : {
                "length" : 12,
                "formFirstName" : firstName,
                "formLastName" : lastName,
                "formCountry" : country
            }
        }
    });

};
```

Comment: It would be good if you can supply some of your code as an example, so that people can try to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @JakobRunge Please check out the javascript code that I've added.

Comment: Thanks. You might also want to look at {[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15827039/448591),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3207472/448591)}, which discuss similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your approach to use the `delete` option should work in theory. So I'm not taking the path to try and reproduce that without knowing if we've possibly got a different setup anyway. Instead I recommend using the
[ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) function together with updated [ajax.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) to update the data currently held in the table.
A possible adjustment of your code would than look like this:

```
function initializeDataTable() {
    return $('#userDetailsTable').dataTable({
            "destroy" : true,
        "pageLength" : 12,
        "processing" : true,
        "serverSide" : true,
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : '/fetchSearchResults',
            "type" : 'POST',
            "data" : {
                "length" : 12,
                "formFirstName" : firstName,
                "formLastName" : lastName,
                "formCountry" : country
            }
        }
    });
};

var processFormData = (function(){
    var table = null;
    return function(){
        var firstName = document.userDetailsTable.firstName.value;
        var lastName = document.userDetailsTable.lastName.value;
        var country = document.userDetailsTable.country.value;

        if (firstName == "" || lastName == "" || country == "") {
            bootbox.alert("Please fill in all fields!");
        } else if (table !== null) {
            table.ajax.data.firstName = firstName;
            table.ajax.data.lastName = lastName;
            table.ajax.data.country = country;
            table.ajax.reload();
        } else {
            table = initializeDataTable();
        }
    };
})();
```

Calling `processFormData()` should than give you an updated table. I've not tested this code though.

Comment: Thanks @Jakob Runge! I used your idea of reloading the datatable rather than destroying and reinitializing it every time the user submits a new form, although I changed the code a bit. The table variable should be global and not local. Also, you cannot simply change the ajax data in the processFormData method. It has to be changed it in the ajax call itself. 
Thanks for your input!

Comment: @TejasiLatkar nice to hear it has helped you :) I'd love it if you could accept my answer as it helped solve your problem.